# Need guidance in using LISTAGG

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT id,pid,apn_nbr 
FROM(
sELECT id, pid,case WHEN listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)= '' THEN 'null'
ELSE listagg(distinct apn_nbr,',') within group(order by apn_nbr) END as apn_nbr

FROM
(SELECT max(f1.pid) as  pid,
                        f1.id,
                        apn_nbr,
                        date
FROM table_1 f1 
JOIN table_2 d1 ON 
f1.process_id = d1.process_id 
WHERE apn_nbr is not null and id=1234576
GROUP BY id,apn_nbr,date,) 
group by id,pid)
WHERE APN_NBR IS NOT NULL 
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by ID order by PID desc) = 1;
```

The result I'm getting when I run the above query is:

```
ID          PID                                                 APN_NBR
228887143   91616341263                                         108051468,145010014,147010037,960049392,960057955,960098393,960098621,960169763,960183667,960247935,960290544,960290545,960326343,960545263,970002302
228887146   52655416407                                         108010224,184070159,960010235,960018534,960070069,960082736,960086586,960111804,960169763,960450519,960537135,960537137,970020211,970033955
228887148   50304710850                                         111011119,136010478,137750338,184700156,188320007,960032041,960072024,960264356,960300892,960457665,970003002,970004388
228887150   72523300271                                         182050695,960529661,960538276,970110690
228887187   272662636613                                        108010505,148050070
```

pid_ind and qid_ind columns are coming from table_2

I need to use the below conditions in the SELECT statement.

```
iff( pid_ind = 'TRUE', concat(apn_nbr, ':', 'high'), NULL) 
AS pid_ind,

iff( qid_ind = 'TRUE', concat(apn_nbr, ':', 'low'), NULL) 
AS qid_ind
```

When I add these conditions in the SELECT statement and adding the column names in GROUP BY,
I'm not getting values separated by commas.

Can anyone guide me on this logic?

The final result should look like this:

```
ID          PID           APN_NBR                                        pid_ind                                              qid_ind
228887143   91616341263    108051468,145010014,147010037,960049392       108051468,145010014,147010037,960049392:increased    NULL
228887146   52655416407    108010224,184070159,960010235,960018534       108010224,184070159,960010235,960018534:increased    NULL 
228887148   50304710850    111011119,136010478,137750338,184700156       111011119,136010478,137750338,184700156:increased    NULL
228887150   72523300271    182050695,960529661,960538276,970110690        NULL                                                182050695,960529661,960538276,970110690:decreased
228887187   272662636613   108010505,148050070                            NULL                                                108010505,148050070:decreased
```

Comment: Can you show a) the how the `:high` and `:low` output is expected to look please, to help workout where this should happen.

Comment: Also you don't use `PID_IND` or `QID_IND` but I am going to guess you are doing this in the inner, because that's where your SQL is invalid..

Comment: I tried using PID_IND and QID_IND in  the inner query, but while using APN_NBR                                 in the OUTER QUERY GROUP BY clause, I didn't get the result as expected. i.e. APN_NBR column is not getting comma separated values.

Comment: I want to display APN_NBR and PID_IND or QID_IND with comma separated values. And indicator columns to be concatenated with high or low

Comment: so you want "high" and "low" but show desired output of "increased" and "decreased"?

Comment: Yes, I want to display high and low in the result. I will check and get back to you for the sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want it doing it after the listagg makes sense, but then the two flags will need to be progated out from table1/2 on the inside, also I assume/hope that are all the same.

```
SELECT
    id,
    pid,
    apn_nbr,
    iff(pid_ind = 'TRUE', apn_nbr||':high', NULL) AS pid_ind,
    iff(qid_ind = 'TRUE', apn_nbr||':low', NULL) AS qid_ind
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        pid,
        pid_ind,
        qid_ind,
        case
            WHEN listagg(DISTINCT apn_nbr, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY apn_nbr)= '' THEN 'null'
            ELSE listagg(distinct apn_nbr,',') within group(order by apn_nbr) 
        END as apn_nbr
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            max(f1.pid) as  pid,
            f1.id,
            apn_nbr,
            date,
            pid_ind,
            qid_ind
        FROM table_1 f1 
        JOIN table_2 d1 
            ON f1.process_id = d1.process_id 
        WHERE apn_nbr is not null and id=1234576
        GROUP BY id, apn_nbr, date, pid_ind, qid_ind
    ) 
    group by id,pid,pid_ind, qid_ind
)
WHERE APN_NBR IS NOT NULL 
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by ID order by PID desc) = 1;
```

but if `pid_ind` and `qid_ind` are not 100% all the same for each `id,date` this will fragment you data into "more" groupings, of which all but the last will disappear via that ROW_NUMBER. Which probably want to be ORDER BY date, given it's the grouping clause you are sorting by and then dropping. Which actually means you could filter the data a head of time to only keep that latest date stuff all the way back there...

Comment: Have you honestly asked yourself if asking all these questions has helped you learn how to write SQL or not, because you are still making the same mistakes, and still not understanding more or less the same core principles. The fact that you have named this a LISTARG question, when it really has nothing todo with listarg, accept you are adding more details to a listarg result, but later, so not listarg at all.

Comment: you might find this interesting reading. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions